# Invoking write/read_reg vr_ad macro from a virtual sequence in Specman

Tags: specman, uvm, e

Is there a way that a virtual sequence can directly call a `vr_ad` `write_reg` or `read_reg` macro without me having to create a `vr_ad_sequence` that does the same thing?

To illustrate more clearly, here is my current implementation:

```
<'
extend vr_ad_sequence_kind : [WR_DMA_POLL];
extend WR_DMA_POLL vr_ad_sequence {
    !dma_poll : DMA_POLL vr_ad_reg;

    body() @driver.clock is only {
        write_reg dma_poll val 0xdeadbeef;
    };
};

extend MAIN soc_tb_virtual_sequence {
    !write_dma_poll : WR_DMA_POLL vr_ad_sequence;

    body() @driver.clock is only {
        message(LOW, "TEST START");
        do write_dma_poll on driver.reg_driver;
    };
};
'>
```

Why can't it be, or is it possible to implement this way?

```
extend MAIN soc_tb_virtual_sequence {
    !dma_poll : DMA_POLL vr_ad_reg;

    body() @driver.clock is only {
        message(LOW, "TEST START");
        write_reg {.dest_driver == driver.reg_driver} dma_poll;
        read_reg {.dest_driver == driver.reg_driver} dma_poll;
    };
};
```

Thank you in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible starting with *vr_ad* 13.20 (or maybe slightly older). You almost had it in your question. The correct syntax is:

```
extend MAIN soc_tb_virtual_sequence {
    !dma_poll : DMA_POLL vr_ad_reg;

    body() @driver.clock is only {
        message(LOW, "TEST START");
        write_reg {.driver == driver.reg_driver} dma_poll;
        read_reg {.driver == driver.reg_driver} dma_poll;
    };
};
```

The first set of `{...}` delimits the operation generate block, where you can constrain how to access the register. These constraints will be passed to the `vr_ad_operation` that gets generated as part of the access.

Comment: I was about to comment that the solution is not working for me. I only had an incorrect setup of vr_ad. It's working perfectly fine now. Thanks a lot!